# How do I determine if there are X numbers of time slots in a row?

Tags: php

Given the following array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [startTime] => 2021-03-18 16:00:00 [endTime] => 2021-03-18 16:30:00 )
    [1] => Array ( [startTime] => 2021-03-18 16:30:00 [endTime] => 2021-03-18 17:00:00 )
    [2] => Array ( [startTime] => 2021-03-18 19:00:00 [endTime] => 2021-03-18 19:30:00 )
    [3] => Array ( [startTime] => 2021-03-18 19:30:00 [endTime] => 2021-03-18 20:00:00 )
    [4] => Array ( [startTime] => 2021-03-18 20:00:00 [endTime] => 2021-03-18 20:30:00 )
    [5] => Array ( [startTime] => 2021-03-18 20:30:00 [endTime] => 2021-03-18 21:00:00 )
)
```

What would be a good method to loop through the array and check if there are X numbers of time slots in a row?

For example, if X = 4, then 19:00-19:30, 19:30-20:00, 20:00-20:30, and 20:30-21:00, and 16:00-16:30, 16:30-17:00, 17:00-17:30, and 17:30-18:00 are in a row.

Edit: A bit messy, but this is what I've written so far, and it doesn't work (though I think I'm on the right track).

```
$newAvailableTimes = array();
$counter = 0;
for ($i=0; $i < count($availableTimes); $i++) { 
    if (($i != (count($availableTimes)-1)) && $availableTimes[$i]["endTime"] == $availableTimes[$i+1]["startTime"]) {
        $counter += 1;
        if ($counter == $time) {
           for ($x=($i-$counter); $x <= $i; $x++) { 
              $newAvailableTimes[] = array($availableTimes[$x]["startTime"], $availableTimes[$x]["endTime"]);
            }
            $counter = 0;
        }
    }
    if ($i == (count($availableTimes))-1) {
        if ($availableTimes[$i]["startTime"] == $availableTimes[$i-1]["endTime"]) {
           counter += 1;
            if ($counter == $time) {
              for ($x=($i-$counter); $x <= $i; $x++) {
                    $newAvailableTimes[] = array($availableTimes[$x]["startTime"], $availableTimes[$x]["endTime"]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

$counter being X

Comment: Please show us the code you have written so far.

Comment: Just did. I think I'm somewhat on the right track.

Comment: First of all, please make it easier for everyone to experiment with your code, by posting your data as a `var_export`, instead of a print_r or var_dump result.

Comment: What result do you want here, when you say “check”? Do you simply need a true/false, depending on whether 4 such consecutive time slots exist, or do you want the specific slots returned?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if you want to figure out if you have the X amount of timeslots available at all or what timeslots they are. Anyway here's the code for the first scenario and easily adapted for the second.

```
function getConsecutiveTimeslots(array $availableSlots, int $requiredTimeslotsInARow): ?array {
    $consecutiveSlots = [];
    $consecutiveSlotCount = 0;
    foreach ($availableSlots as $availableSlot) {
        if (!isset($consecutiveSlots[$consecutiveSlotCount])) {
            $consecutiveSlots[$consecutiveSlotCount] = [$availableSlot];
            continue;
        }

        $lastSlot = end($consecutiveSlots[$consecutiveSlotCount]);
        if ($availableSlot['startTime'] === $lastSlot['endTime']) {
            $consecutiveSlots[$consecutiveSlotCount][] = $availableSlot;
            continue;
        }

        $consecutiveSlotCount++;
    }

    foreach ($consecutiveSlots as $consecutiveSlot) {
        if (count($consecutiveSlot) >= $requiredTimeslotsInARow) {
            return $consecutiveSlot;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

It can be used like

```
$availableTimes = [
    ['startTime' => '2021-03-18 16:00:00', 'endTime' => '2021-03-18 16:30:00'],
    ['startTime' => '2021-03-18 16:30:00', 'endTime' => '2021-03-18 17:00:00'],
    ['startTime' => '2021-03-18 19:00:00', 'endTime' => '2021-03-18 19:30:00'],
    ['startTime' => '2021-03-18 19:30:00', 'endTime' => '2021-03-18 20:00:00'],
    ['startTime' => '2021-03-18 20:00:00', 'endTime' => '2021-03-18 20:30:00'],
    ['startTime' => '2021-03-18 20:30:00', 'endTime' => '2021-03-18 21:00:00'],
];
$requiredTimeslotsInARow = 4;

getConsecutiveTimeslots($availableTimes, $requiredTimeslotsInARow);
// returns an array of times or null if nothing could be found
```

Update: I've modified the code so it will now return you the timeslots if available, otherwise it will return `null`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's basically what I was looking for, but I wanted the second scenario (return array of timeslots). I should've clarified that in my original post but oh well.

Would you be willing to change the code so it fits the second scenario? I've tried but can't figure it out.

Comment: I've modified the code so it will now return you the timeslots if available